# how to open com.android.contacts/.CallDetalActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, calllog

i want to open calldetail activity to see a contact call log info.

i take uri with this code

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER))));
```

now if i use

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,lookupUri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

it opens the calls tab on my phone but not the calldetail activity. how can i display calldetail activity with lookupUri?

EDIT: thanks to commonsware i've did it modyfing

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, Uri.encode(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE` as the MIME type of your `Intent`.